# Problems sending a datetime field with Retrofit to a Django REST Framework endpoint

Tags: datetime, django-rest-framework, retrofit

Using Retrofit I can send and receive data fine, including dates, but when I use @Multipart it stops working.

This is the log of my data being sent:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post_date"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 26
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
"2015-08-06T19:37:14.000Z"
```

Here's the error I get:

```
{"post_date": ["Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]"]}
```

If I omit the date_time field all the other fields transfer properly. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, the data I'm sending matches the date format that DRF is expecting, but it doesn't seem to think so.

Edit: If I use Postman and send the values that Retrofit claims to be sending it works. I can copy and paste the date above (without quotes) and it submits just fine.

Edit 2: I figured out the problem, the quotes around the date value in my log aren't just in my log, they are added to the date when sending the value to the server. So....how do I convince Retrofit that date values don't need extra quotes around them?

Edit 3: Looks like the issue is that Gson adds quotes to a date when it gets formatted for JSON then Retrofit just sends the value that Gson provides. If you're sending a multi-part message you don't want those quotes though. Not sure how to proceed, created an issue on the Retrofit github page. I know Retrofit either strips quotes from strings before sending them as part of a multipart message, or never adds them in the first place, seems like the same strategy should be used for dates.

Comment: Got the same Problem within my js File, stil i built my Json Data by my own and let Django handle this. Since Formating was the only cause in  my case i post the format:  
      ``var today = new Date();

      var dd = today.getDate();  
      var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!  
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      var hh = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var secs = today.getSeconds();
      
      var now = yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+"T"+hh+":"+m+":"+secs;``

Answer (score 0):

Extracting answer from k4yaman comment.

> Got the same Problem within my js File, stil i built my Json Data by
>   my own and let Django handle this. Since Formating was the only cause
>   in my case i post the format.

```
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
var hh = today.getHours(); 
var m = today.getMinutes(); 
var secs = today.getSeconds(); 
var now = yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+"T"+hh+":"+m+":"+secs
```